# how to use zendesk api to get a ticket through api based on query in c#

Tags: c#, zendesk, zendesk-api

I want to fetch a ticket through zendesk api but not getting response when i add a extra item to search query

here is my postman request

`https://url/api/v2/search.json?query=type:ticket tags:payment`

with above i am getting 100 records but when i add any extra parameter to query i am unable to get records

`https://url/api/v2/search.json?query=type:ticket tags:payment custom_fields_id :8989898 custom_fields_value :Vhd-5`

`{ "url": "url.json", "id": 454545, "external_id": null, "created_at": "2023-08-08T21:44:57Z", "updated_at": "2023-08-08T21:44:57Z", "type": "xyz", "subject": "subject", "description": "description", "priority": null, "status": "open", "recipient": null, "group_id": null, "tags": [ "payment" ], "custom_fields": [ { "id": 45454545, "value": null }, { "id": 8989898, "value": "Vhd-5" } ], "result_type": "ticket" }`
I want to know how i can fetch records with id & value in custom fields is postman query is correct or any change is required

Comment: The URI parameters are after the question mark and when you have multiple parameters they are separated with an ampersand.   See : https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-get-url-parameters.html